# How do I open a specific google folder in a new tab using apps script through a spreadhsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a simpe script that I can add to the UI that opens a specific Google drive Folder when pressed.

[This is the simple Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189KnXvQ7MZhiafyTkM2dot4ik2Nyrm1B40BgrpxvlBM/edit?usp=sharing)

I've created a short script that opens the Womble Folder in my google drive,  and added a UI called Open Womble Folder. It works ok, but I don't think this is the best way to do this. Is there a more Google-centric, and perhaps more elegant way to open a google folder in a new tab?

I have a lot of other projects that need this facility and I want to know that I'm on the right track.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
function openDriveFolder(){
  var html = "<script>window.open('https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HPEQmmWo6ALNP4zw8FZCtu2C3zFYCdZs?usp=sharing');google.script.host.close();</script>";  
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Womble Drive Folder');
  }
```

Comment: I think that your script is the simple method. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I don't think this is the best way to do this.` and `a more Google-centric, and perhaps more elegant way to open a google folder in a new tab`. In order to see the vision of your goal, can I ask you about `the best way` and `a more Google-centric, and perhaps more elegant way` you expect?

Comment: If you feel this is the best method, then I am grateful for your time and reply. I just wondered if there was a specific google apps script command to open a google folder rather than using the html script - I obviously use the google apps script....Your English is perfect.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, unfortunately, there are no methods for directly open the URL in the methods of Google Apps Script. So in this case, I think that your script is the answer. For example, how about requesting your goal for the Google issue tracker as the future request? https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker